# Why is the text of the file displayed twice

Tags: c++, c++20

I have been working on a project which needs to read the text from a .txt file. But I get the text displayed in the console twice.

Here is the *CreateFiles.cpp*

```
#include "CreateFiles.h"
void createF()
{
    std::fstream fs{ "C:\\Users\\bahge\\source\\repos\\Education\\Education\\myfile.txt" };

    std::string s;

    while (fs)
    {
        std::getline(fs, s);
        
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }
}
```

And the *CreateFiles.h*

```
#pragma once
#ifndef CREATE_FILES
#define CREATE_FILES
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
void createF();
#endif // !CREATE_FILES
```

Here is the *file's content*

```
StackOverflow
```

And the *output from the console*

```
StackOverflow
StackOverflow

C:\Users\bahge\source\repos\Education\x64\Debug\Education.exe (process 39072) exited with code 0.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

Comment: Test the return value of getline before printing. You're just printing the last line twice: once as itself, and once after you reach the end of the file.

Comment: `std::getline(fs, s);` fails, but you don't check to see that it failed.  Oopsies.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are encountering a variation of [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/).

You are ignoring the stream's state after `getline()` returns. Your file has only 1 line in it, so `s` is not valid (and in your case, is unchanged) after the 2nd read fails, but you are not handling that condition correctly, so you are printing `s` when you should not be.

You need to change your loop from this:

```
while (fs)
{
    std::getline(fs, s);
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

To this instead:

```
while (std::getline(fs, s))
{
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```